# when we remove the simple product from configurable product how we can compare the before save and after save child product ids

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, child

[image]when we remove any simple product from configurable product that time how we can get remove product ids,i am try with     "**catalogue_product_save_after**"    "**catalogue_product_save_before**" but this thing is not working it will give me same data before product delete data,
if i am use only one event  `<event name="catalogue_product_save_after">` then it will give me correct  data

Comment: Try `catalog_product_save_commit_after` event.

Comment: i am unable to find out this event name in magneto 2, if this event is exist then how we can compare parent product data before save and after save in magento 2

Comment: @RAJDIPJALONDHARA can you specify into some more details, what you are trying to do? So we can suggest solution accordingly.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya what i want is when we remove any child(simple) product from the parent(configurable) product  that time i want to know which child is remove from that parent product so i can perform different operation on that child product

i am also attach screen shot on that my main question so may that will help to to understand my actual question

Answer (score 0):

The `Remove Product` options which show on your screenshot is comes from this file :

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/web/template/components/actions-list.html

```
<li>
            <a class="action-menu-item" data-bind="
                click: function(){
                    $parent.closeList($record().index);
                    $parent.processingDeleteRecord($record().index, $record().recordId);
                },
                text: $t('Remove Product')
            "></a>
        </li>
```

Now, when you debug this code, then found to remove that record from that grid this call

> $parent.processingDeleteRecord($record().index, $record().recordId);

And `processingDeleteRecord` function is available into this file.

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows.js

```
processingDeleteRecord: function (index, recordId) {
            this.deleteRecord(index, recordId);
},
```

So for your requirement, you need to `override` this file :

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows.js
```

into your `custom extension` and do the another action into that `processingDeleteRecord function`.